# How to render objects inside an objects array

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of 3 objects

```
  const parts = [
    {
      name: "Fundamentals of React",
      exercises: 10
    },
    {
      name: "Using props to pass data",
      exercises: 7
    },
    {
      name: "State of a component",
      exercises: 14
    }
  ];
```

I can get all objects content on the console

```
 parts.forEach((value) => {
   console.log(value);});
```

I want to use the Content component to display the content of the array of objects, but I can´t figure out how to do it.

On the code below I try to log the props, but I am not getting any, so nothing is rendered.

```
const Content = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <div><h1>{props.parts}</h1></div>;
```

[Here is my code in code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-snow-g8pjo?file=/src/App.js:331-425)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your code that you don't have passed the parts array to the Content component. In order to receive the props you should do something like this:

```
<Content parts={parts} />
```

Then you'll see the array in the Content's `console.log()` and therefore you'll be able to render the array in the component. For example

```
const Content = (props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <div>{props.parts[0].name}</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all pass parts as a prop in App.js

```
  <Content parts={parts}/>
```

Now we have access to the parts array in Content. Now all you have to do is use a map function to render the array items.

```
const Content = (props) => {
  console.log(props.parts);
  return props.parts.map(item => (
    <div>{item.name}</div>
  ))
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When we want to render some elements from an array of objects, `Array.map` is the method that is useful. The problem with `Array.forEach` is that it will not return anything, it'll be useful when we want to manipulate the array objects in-place while looping.

We can pass the `parts` to the `Content` component as prop like below

```
//Pass `parts` array as `data` to `Content` component
<Content data={parts}/>
```

and the passed data can be accessed in different ways

```
const Content = ({ data }) => {
  //use the passed `parts` array as `data` for rendering or for any other purposes
}

OR

const Content = props => {
  //`parts` array can be accessed using `props.data`
}
```

```js
const parts = [
    { name: "Fundamentals of React", exercises: 10},
    { name: "Using props to pass data", exercises: 7 },
    { name: "State of a component", exercises: 14 }
];

const Content = ({ data }) => {
  return data.map(obj => (
    <div key={obj.name}>
      {obj.name}: {obj.exercises}
    </div>
  ))
}

const App = () => {
  return (<div>
    <header>Header</header>
    <Content data={parts}/>
  </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the `parts`as prop to the `Content`

```
<Content parts={parts} />
```

then just iterate the parts and show their content

```
const Content = ({ parts }) => {  
  return (
    <div>
      {parts.map((part, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <h1>{part.name}</h1> 
          <p>{part.exercises}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```